# ARC and MBProgressHUD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm trying to convert my app to  ARC and the converter is throwing up an error when I try to show and hide the MBProgressHUD. The code and error are below.

```
hud = [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
// error: Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'MBProgressHUD *' is disallowed with ARC
```

I don't understand what booleans have anything to do with in this case. Do you have any ideas about what is causing this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hideHUDForView` returns a BOOL, that indicates if the progressHUD was hidden or not. ARC is complaining about the type of the variable `hud`, which should be a BOOL, not a MBProgressHUD object.

The documentation for this method can be found here: http://orfoundation.github.com/ORFoundation/Classes/MBProgressHUD.html#//api/name/hideHUDForView:animated: